# Matrix factorization based recommendation for like/dislike/unknown data

Tags: recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, matrix-factorization

Most literature focus on either explicit rating data or implicit (like/unknown) data. Are there any good publications to handle like/dislike/unknown data? That is, in the data matrix there are three values, and I'd like to recommend from unknown entries.

And are there any good open source implementations on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With like and dislike, you already have explicit rating data. You can use standard collaborative filtering with user and item normalization. You can also check out OrdRec: An Ordinal Model for Predicting Personalized Item Rating Distributions, which just takes an ordinal ranking of item ratings. That is, you can say that Like is better than Dislike, and let the algorithm figure out the best ranking-to-rating mapping before doing standard item-item collaborative filtering. Download [LensKit](http://lenskit.org/) and use the included OrdRec algorithm.